# Connect to SQL SERVER in Qt on Linux

Tags: sql, linux, qt, raspbian

I have to use Microsoft SQL database in Qt on Raspbian and I wonder whether is it possible. If so, use of which version (4 or 5) is easier to achieve it (building plugins etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to Microsoft SQL Server from QT / Rasbpian is perfectly possible.

You need to install / use client side ODBC drivers, like unixODBC and FreeTDS.